# Deciding behaviour of $f(x)=2x^3− 9x^2 + 12x + 3$ in the interval $[0,2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When we find the maxima and minima of this function, a maxima occurs at x=1 and a minima at x=2.

Can we say without calculating f(0) that it would be the minimum value of the function in the interval [0,2], since at - infinity, the function is negative and so to reach a (positive) maxima at x=1, it would need to have a real root, that is, cross the x-axis.

Or do we need to calculate f(0) and f(2) and then say that since f(0) is less than f(2), it is our answer.

In other words, is it possible for f(0) to be greater than f(2) for a cubic function like this which moves from -infinity to +infinity at extremes and has turning points at x=1 and x=2 ?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, a cubic has always exactly one turning point. Assuming the derivate has two distinct real roots : If the leading coefficient is positive , the maximum is at the smaller root of the derivate and the minimum at the larger. Vice versa, if the leading coefficient is negative. To see this, consider the monotony intervals.

Comment: @Peter why do you say that a cubic has exactly one turning point? It can have up to $2$ turning points, no?

Comment: @MathLover I used the wrong terminology. I meant an inflection point. And I interpreted "turning point " wrongly to be an inflection point. Sorry for the possible confusion.

Comment: @Peter sure, that makes sense.

Comment: Surely, we can conclude $f(0)<f(1)$ without calculating $f(0)$ , since for $x\le 1$, the function is strictly increasing. But then it strictly decreases, hence we cannot conclude $f(0)<f(2)$

Comment: @Peter, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Your "In other words, is it possible..." paragraph contains a legitimate question that I wish to evade.  With respect to the original question, I always simply solve $f'(x) = 0$ and then for each of the roots $r$, compare $f''(r)$ against $0$. Why would I ever need to compute $f(0)$?  Another way of saying the same thing is that $f(x-s)$ is going to have the same shape as $f(x)$ except that the graph has been moved $s$ units to the right.  Therefore, I have trouble attaching immediate significance to $f(x_1)$, for any value $x_1$, prior to examining $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of
$$
f(x)=2x^3-9x^2+12x+3
$$
is
$$
f'(x)=6x^2-18x+12
$$
which equals $0$ when $x^2-3x+2=0$, i.e. when $x=1$ or $x=2$. Without even thinking about minima or maxima, we know that $f(0)$ is a strong contender for being the smallest value in the interval $[0,2]$, as $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,1]$. However, since $f$ is strictly *decreasing* on $[1,2]$, we need to check if the graph dips down low enough so that $f(2)<f(0)$. Therefore, it is not sufficient to say that $f(0)$ is the smallest value without checking first what the value of $f(2)$ is.

In this particular case, we get that $f(0)=3$, and that $f(2)=7$, so it turns out that the graph *does not* dip down low enough. However, we *must* check the endpoints in the interval to be sure that we have reached the right conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

In a limited interval, you have to calculate the value at both ends to be sure. Both ends may not be related to the behavior at minus infinity and plus infinity